# Add arrays of unequal lengths in fortran up till a common index

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm sorry if this question is basic, but I taught myself fortran and I've looked at this code and tried lots of things that I'm beginning to get confused.
I performed an interpolation and wrote the output to an array, and I would like to add that array to another array that exists in the code, but my addition gives totally weird results. From the plot I attached, I expect the addition (Total cls) to follow the red dashed line (which is the same addition but done outside the code manually), bit instead follows the yellow line.

```
            use trilinear
            use array_mod
            use variables

            implicit none
            integer (cosmosis_block) :: block
            integer (cosmosis_status) :: status

            integer, parameter :: input_set = 1
            real  :: cls(2:standard_lmax_ksz,1:4)
            real(8)  :: cls_double(2:standard_lmax_ksz,1:4), cls_phi(2:standard_lmax)
            real(8)  :: cls_final(2:standard_lmax_ksz,1)
            integer  :: ell(2:standard_lmax_ksz), l
            logical, parameter :: switch_polarization_convention = .false.  
            real(8), DIMENSION(1448) :: interpolated_array
            real(8) :: inner_coord(1448,3)
            real(8) :: lambda
            real(8) :: mass
            real(8), DIMENSION(1448,27) :: coord
            integer :: m, max_rows, n, lam, inner_row
            REAL(8)  :: interpolated_value(1:standard_lmax_ksz)
            real(8) :: interpolated_index

            integer :: zeta
            Logical :: first_time = .True.
            CHARACTER(len=100) :: FN
            type(CambParams) :: params
            character(len=3),dimension(3) :: mass_array
            N=3                                     
            mass_array(1) = '2e8'
            mass_array(2) = '2e9'
            mass_array(3) = '3e9'
            !!!

            status = 0

            call CAMB_GetCls(cls, standard_lmax_ksz, input_set, switch_polarization_convention)
            cls_double(:,1:4) = cls * 7.4311e12  !cmb output scale       

            if(first_time) then
            max_rows=1448
                    lam = 80
                    DO I=1,N
                            lam = lam + 60
                            zeta=20
                            do j=1,N
                                 zeta = zeta + 20
                                    do k=1,N
                                          WRITE(FN,10)lam,zeta(mass_array(k))!,k=1,N)
                                    WRITE(6,*)FN!filename
                                    OPEN(99,FILE=FN, action='read', status='old',position='rewind')
                                    do inner_row=1,max_rows
                                            read (99,*)(inner_coord(inner_row,l),l=1,3)
                                            coord(:,9*I+3*j+k-12)=inner_coord(:,3)
                                    end do
                                    CLOSE(99)       
                                    end do
                            end do
                    END DO
            10 FORMAT('4e3_2048_',(I3.0),'',(I2.2),'',(A3),'.ksz_cl.txt') !length of thisis decided by FN
            print *, first_time
            first_time = .False.
            endif
            interpolated_array = trilinear_mod(params%lambda_ksz, params%zeta_ksz, params%mmin_ksz, coord)

           open (unit=96, file='interpolated_array_new.txt')!, action='write')!, status='replace')            
            do n = 2, 17
                    interpolated_index = n
                    interpolated_value = 0
                    write(96,'(2f16.10)') interpolated_index, interpolated_value
            end do
            do m = 1,max_rows-1
                    write(96,'(2f16.10)') inner_coord(m,1), interpolated_array(m)
                    do n = 1,17
                            interpolated_index = inner_coord(m,1)+n
                            interpolated_value = interpolated_array(m)*(1-n/18.) + interpolated_array(m+1)*(n/18.)
                            write(96,'(2f16.10)') interpolated_index, interpolated_value
                    end do
            end do
            close(96)

            cls_final(:,1) = cls_double(:,1) + interpolated_value
```

[image: plot of the aarrays]

Comment: Please show a short, complete code which has the problem you seeing, and tell us what results you are getting, why you think they are weird, and what you think they should be. I'm afraid with what is given it is all but impossible to answer your question.

Comment: I've updated the code and a plot showing the result I get @Ian Bush

Comment: Complete code, please - I can't see the modules you use, and I can't see an end statement. Also real( 8 ) is not portable and so very bad practice, see numerous questions here explaining why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue here is you have defined interpolated_value as an Array
REAL(8)  :: interpolated_value(1:standard_lmax_ksz)

And used it as a scaler in multiple places(one example is)
interpolated_value = 0

If you put
IMPLICIT NONE before your definitions, you'll get better catches on these kinds of things.

Without more detail like atleast part of your input file, this is all we can probably offer.

Comment: How does `implicit none` help detect unintended assignment to a whole array?

Comment: Thanks @Cocofalco. I've updated the code and also attached a plot. Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: @francescalus My compiler isn't giving any errors about this array/scaler, I assumed it was ignoring the array definition and defining it as an integer. Assumed the ImpNone would flag the undefined scaler. If you want I can take that out of the answer.

Comment: @user9404237 your updated code still uses the array as a scaler